# Binding Data to Asp.net HighCharts using Jquery Json

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, highcharts

I have a asp.net chart which shows some attendance of month.

I have a dropdown which shows the month name. The user will select the month from the dropdown and click on a button.

On this button click, I want to call ActionResult mettod, which will fetch the data from a database of selected month and bind the data to chart(dotnet.highcharts).

I want to know if I can bind data to an asp.net chart with specific values.
Can anyone please let me know how to do this?

Comment: You'll get much better answers if you show what you've tried and what has and hasn't worked.  Include code and any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your method would probably return JsonResult in that case. Once you receive that json on the client side (through ajax request e.g.) you would submit it to Highcharts series property.

Comment: i want to pass parameter from view to controller in order to filter my jsonResult, how can I do that ?